# How to get array combinations in php?

Tags: php

I have a array in php

```
array(100,125,135);
```

I would like to know How I can get all combinations like in the below EG ?

```
Eg:100=>125,100=>135,125=>100,125=>135,135=>100,135=>125
```

I Tried something like this

```
$selected_items = array(100,125,135);
$total = count($selected_items);
$combination = array();
$newcom=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){           
        if($newcom <= $total-1) $newcom = $newcom-1;
        echo  $newcom."-----";
         $combination[$i] = array($selected_items[$i]=> $selected_items[$newcom]);
            $newcom = $i+1;  
    }
```

But this is not working to get all combinations

Please help me.

Comment: Hint: You need two loops.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$temp = array(1, 2, 3);
$result = array();

foreach ($temp as $value)
{
    foreach ($temp as $value2)
    {
       if ($value != $value2) $result[$value] = $value2;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is showing only Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)

Comment: I can't see combination of 1,2

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array(100,125,135);
$output = array();
foreach ($a as  $first) {
    $arr[$first]=array();
    foreach ($a as $second) {
        if($first != $second)
            $arr[$first][] = $second;
    }

}
$output = $arr;
print_r($output);
```

Comment: That's not a problem. You can always delete your answer here.

Comment: @defaultlocale check above one is not correct .. hahha which has 2 votes

Comment: @Apptester Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [0] => 125
            [1] => 135
        )

    [125] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 135
        )

    [135] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 125
        )

)

Comment: my bad, sorry. Didn't realize that your answer was different. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple of foreach loops -

```
$sequence     = [100, 125, 135];
$permutations = [];

foreach ($sequence as $value) {
    foreach ($sequence as $value2) {
        if ($value != $value2) {
            $permutations[] = [$value => $value2];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done.
An array contains a key and a value.
In your example you want an array where the keys can be the same.
You will just overwrite your values
So if you run your example the result will be somthing like the following:

```
 100=>135
,125=>135
,135=>125
```

A possible solution can be multidimensional arrays:

```
 100=>array(125, 135)
,125=>array(100, 135)
,135=>array(100, 125)
```